# SBTPlayground database doesn't show snippets

Tags: ibm-sbt

When I install the SBTPlayground database on our Domino 8.5.3 server and view it in the browser. There are no snippets displayed in the left column.
The snippets are present in the database.
And when I look in the Domino Designer I see such as in the snippetTree custom control
snippetDoc.getSnippetsAsJson() where snippetDoc is a Managed bean.
But I can not find which view is used.
In the console of the server there is no errors printed regarding this problem.
In the screenshot you will see the leftcolumn.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Login 
Click Manage (on right)
Click Import / Export
Click New Import Source
[image: Import source dialog]
Input the Name
Input the directory of {sbtsdk}/source/com.ibm.sbt.sample.web/WebContent/js/
Click Save

Go back to the Playground

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed, by installing the XPages Bazaar project update site

Answer (score 0):

Can you see any error in the Javascript console, using Firebug for example? According to your screenshot, the Dojo classes are not properly loaded, so the tree or the tab are not rendered.

Comment: Phil, I have added a screenhot from firebug, there are several errors. What I was thinking, should the XPages Bazaar database also be installed?

Comment: Yes, this is it. The Bazaar must be installed as it provides a copy of code mirror, which is used to display the programming editor